# Python Only Writes One of Three docs Using open() read() write()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have multiple html files that get copy+pasted into a single word doc for reporting.

I'm trying to combine all files by opening `File1` and copying it into `test.doc`. Then, open `File2` and append into  `test.doc`, and so on.

Python only writes the `File1` into the `test.doc`, and seems to skip `File2` and `File3`.

I've tried looping through each file and writing, but I had the same result. I've tried a few different file types, changing the `.html` to `.txt` .

I think something to do with the `<html>report contents</html>` could be stopping it.

A push in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
import os


    for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        newName = os.path.splitext(file)
        if '.html' in file:
            newFile = file.replace('.html', '.doc')
            os.rename(file, newFile)
    else:
        print('No html files to convert, writing the report')

    mainFile = open('test.doc', 'a')
    File1 = open('FileToCopy1.doc', 'r')
    Read1 = File1.read()
    mainFile.write(Read1)
    File1.close()

    File2 = open('FileToCopy2.doc', 'r')
    Read2 = File2.read()
    mainFile.write(Read2)
    File2.close()

    File3 = open('FileToCopy3.doc', 'r')
    Read3 = File3.read()
    mainFile.write(Read3)
    File3.close()

    mainFile.close()

    exit()
```

Comment: print the value read to make sure you are actually reading the file

Comment: Thanks Pradheep.

I used PyCharms debugger:

I do get str data into the Read1,2, and 3 variables.

Comment: You can't concatenate `html` documents. The document has a beginning and end. Maybe word doesn't recognise anything beyond the first 'end'. Can you check the contents some other way? Try without making the output `.doc`, make it `.html` instead. You'd need to take the contents of the `body` section of each document and concatenate them.

Comment: Peter, you are correct! If I change back to `.html `, I get a correct view. Hmm,  Beautiful Soup looks promising. Thank you Peter.